# how can I access data from class through another class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, instance

Suppose there are three classes A, B and C and they are connected in a way that A has an object instance to B, and B has an object instance to C (A->B->C).
Each of the classes has private data members, getters and setters.

How can I get a value from class C to class A?

The code example:

```
class C{
private:
    int q = 3;
    int w = 2;
    int e = 1;

public:
... setters and getters ...
}

class B{
private:
    C objC;
    int x;
    int y;

public:
... setters and getters ...

}

class A{
private:
    B objB;
    int rows;
    int cols;

public:
  Board{

    if(objB.objC.getValOfQ() > 0){    //this is not working because objC is a private data member of class B
      ....
    }

  }
}
```

Should I write a getter function in class B to access objC or something like that? How to make a public getter for an object?

Here is the error:

```
 'objC' is a private member of 'B'
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] and show the actual compiler error message you get.

Comment: the error message is: 'objC' is a private member of 'B'

Comment: So make a public getter for `objC`?

Comment: Then please add that information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: how to make a public getter for an object tho? sorry I'm new to c++

Comment: Are the classes ever going to be used as "free" classes or are a `C` always going to be held by a `B` that is held by an `A`?

Comment: they are always going to be held by another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you would not be able to directly access `objC` since it is set privately in `objB`.

Another simple solution on top of the one you mentioned, which would kill the purpose of setting `objectB` to `private`, would be to create additional *getter* functions in `objB` that would call the corresponding *getters* in `objC` instead of returning the object.